# Finding f interval trigonometric function

Tags: calculus

How would I find the f interval of the following trigonometric function.

$f(x)=x-2 \sin(x)$ defined on $[0,2\pi]$

I did $f'(x)=1-2 \cos(x)$

$\cos(x)=\frac{1}{2}$

$x=\frac{\pi}{3},\frac{5\pi}{3}$

But when I graph it on wolfram alpha there seem to be more zeroe where it increases and decreases.

Comment: By an analysis of your derivative, the function decreases in the interval $[0,\pi/3]$, then increases in $[\pi/3,5\pi/3]$, then decreases in $[5\pi/3,2\pi]$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No worries, you need only determine when $f(x)$ is increasing or decreasing on for $x \in [0, 2\pi]$

Test between $x = 0$ and $x \lt \pi/3$ (the derivative is negative there).

Test between $x > \pi/3$ and $x < 5\pi/3$, (the derivative is positive there) and then

test the values between $x > 5\pi/3$ and $x\leq 2\pi$ (where the $f'(x)\lt 0$).

The other "zeros" you see occur *outside* of the interval $x \in [0, 2\pi]$.

[image]

So, you need only worry $f(x)$ on the interval $[0, 2\pi]$.

$f(x)$ is decreasing on the intervals $x\in [0, \pi/3)$ and increases on $x\in (\pi/3, 5\pi/3)$, then decreases on the interval $x \in (5\pi/3, 2\pi]$.

Comment: yes that makes sense because it has to be between zero and 2 pi.

Comment: Yes, on your earlier trig function, as well, we can restrict the intervals of where the function was increasing to $x \in [0, 2\pi]$.  Good question.

Comment: I have a quick question when you want to plug in a point to test say 50 degrees do you plug it into the original function not the derivative?

Comment: To test a point $x$ for whether it is increasing or decreasing, you plug it into the derivative: if $f'(x) > 0$ it is increasing there, if $f(x) \lt 0$, it is decreasing there.  To find the actual function value at point x, then plug it into the original function.

Comment: Does that help? Did I answer your question?

Comment: yes it helps but would it not be increasing between pi/3 and 5pi/3 because say you plug in pi/2 at 1-2cos(x) you would get a positive number and would it not increase?

Comment: oops, I got the intervals mixed up when I listed them at the bottom. What you found matches the description I give above the bottom...I corrected the typo! Sorry for the confusion!

Comment: I see ok thanks for answering my questions.

Comment: Your welcome, Fernando :-)